# Why doesn't work the `context` option of the `webpack.config.js` file?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Webpack v3.0.0

The current directory is where the `webpack.config.js` file is located. This is its content:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    entry: 'index.js',
    output:{
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'out'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module:{
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(html)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

at this case I get the error:

> ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'index.js' in
>   'C:\Users\bushmanaa\Desktop\www\src'

But the `C:\Users\bushmanaa\Desktop\www\src\index.js` file exists! Also, such variant of the settings works without error:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    // context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output:{
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'out'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module:{
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(html)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Why it doesn't work when I use the `context` option?

Comment: Can you log what `path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')` actually outputs?

Comment: `C:\Users\bushmanaa\Desktop\www\src`

Comment: What is you re-include the content, but change the entry file to `'./index.js'`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry. That was meant to be "what if".

Comment: Oh... You are right: this change works for my first variant. Thank you!